# Passing a pointer to an object in C++ & error: no matching function for call to

Tags: c++

I'm trying to pass a pointer to a `vector` from one free floating function to another. This all works good, however, when trying to add something to this vector I get a strange compilation error.

```
$ g++ PeekClientRMS.cpp
PeekClientRMS.cpp: In function ‘void testNewWord(std::string, std::vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap> >*)’:
PeekClientRMS.cpp:116:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap> >::push_back(PeekDeque<StringWrap>*&)’
  chainsp->push_back(newpd);
                          ^
PeekClientRMS.cpp:116:26: note: candidate is:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/vector:64:0,
                 from PeekClientRMS.cpp:13:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:901:7: note: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = PeekDeque<StringWrap>; _Alloc = std::allocator<PeekDeque<StringWrap> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = PeekDeque<StringWrap>]
       push_back(const value_type& __x)
       ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:901:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘PeekDeque<StringWrap>*’ to ‘const value_type& {aka const PeekDeque<StringWrap>&}’
```

The problem seems to by introducing my custom class called `StringWrap` instead of `string`. The line of code that is causing this compilation error is `chainsp->push_back(newpd);`

```
void testNewWord(string word, vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap> >* chainsp) {

    PeekDeque<StringWrap>* newpd = new PeekDeque<StringWrap>(100);
    chainsp->push_back(newpd);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){   
    if(argc != 2){
        cerr << "Please specify a SINGLE .txt file to process." << endl;
        return(1);
    }

    vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap> >* chainsp = new vector<PeekDeque<StringWrap> >(); 

    string word;

    string infileName = argv[1];
    ifstream* INFILEp = new ifstream(infileName.c_str(), ios_base::in);

    while ((*INFILEp) >> word) {
        cout << word << endl;
        testNewWord(word, chainsp);
    }

    INFILEp->close();
}
```

It's odd, because I made a simpler version of this program using `vector<string>` and it worked fine. I'm not really sure what this compiler error is saying and where to start debugging?

Comment: You have a vector of objects. You can't push a pointer to one. It seems like a lot of these pointers are unnecessary, too.

Comment: Looks like your vector is parameterized on PeekDeque<StringWrap>, but you are calling push_back on a PeekDeque<StringWrap>*&. Try chainsp->push_back(*newpd);

Comment: `chainsp->push_back(*newpd)` worked!

Comment: For reference, please read this and note some things. Excessively using pointers will only get you into trouble. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb07e7942cbfffc7

Comment: Thank you for that. Much cleaner that way.